# Изменение размеров окна в приложении в зависимости от устройства

Tags: javascript, html, css

В Play Market(и не только, но возьмём его) есть приложения(на ПК это сайты). Устройства которые их скачивают имеют разные размеры экрана.
  Подскажите, как в javaScript(и вообще на сайте) изменять размер "рабочей" области. Один человек смотрит сайт с ПК и всё выглядит красиво и нормально, а другой смотрит с телефона и у него всё сикось-накось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понял я вашего вопроса так как не увидел знак вопроса

Есть такой термин как медиа запросы, делать можно и через javascript но это отлично работает на обычном css

Всё что пишется между

**@media (max-width:960px) { вот здесь  }**

Будет работать только на этом разрешении...

Если надо какое то другое разрешение экрана то в медиа запросе пишите нужную величину экрана, как правило, запросы пишут так что бы 100% попасть в нужную величину то пишется 
это таким образом

**@media only screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-width:960px){ здесь пишут правила }**

что скажет что бы все устройства которые расположены от 640px до 960px выводили такие css стили какие указаны между фигурными скобками и пробелы обязательны

Есть документация по запросам : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Но запросов бывает куча ...от размеров пикселей до ориентации и даже более сложные